# How to sort user input String names in alphabetical order, using String.equals and String.compareTo

Tags: java, sorting, compareto

This program output should be:

```
Enter first : Alexis
Enter Second : Zach
Enter Third : Cassie

Here are sorted the sorted name:

Alexis

Cassie

Zach
```

but if the names are identical it has to output an error message saying the names are identical.

Example
Enter name 1 Alexis
Enter Name 2 Alexis
Enter Name 3 Katie

Names one and two are identical.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class AlexisPriceAssignment6
{
        public static String input = " ";
        public static String input2 = " ";
        public static String input3 = "";


    public static void Greet()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Alexis Price's Name Sorter.");
        System.out.println("All names must be unique.");

    }
    public static void Uinput()
    {
          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first name: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        char one = input.charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter the second name: ");
        input2 = keyboard.nextLine();
        char two = input2.charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter the third name: " );
        input3 = keyboard.nextLine();
        char three = input3.charAt(0);

        System.out.println();
        if (input.equals(input2) )
        {
            System.out.println(input + " is the same as "+ input2);
        }
        if ( input.equals(input3))
        {
           System.out.println(input + " is the same as "+ input3);
        }
        if (input2.equals(input3))
        {
            System.out.println(input2 + " is the same as "+ input3);
        }
        if (input!=(input2))
        {
            sort();
        }


    }

    public static void sort()
    {
        System.out.println("Here are the sorted names.");

        char charArray [] = input.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(charArray);
        String sortedString = new String(charArray);
        System.out.println(sortedString);


    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Greet();
        Uinput();


    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need `String.equals` and `String.compareTo`. `compareTo` is consistent with `equals`, so `a.compareTo(b) == 0 <=> a.equals(b)`.

Comment: The assignment says that I have to use String.equals and String.compareTo.

Answer (score 0):

The check:

```
    if (input!=(input2))
    {
        sort();
    }
```

is both wrong, because `String` uses .equals() method for comparing, and useless, because you already checked all three combinations by comparing each pair directly. Just call the sort() method after the 3 `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TreeSet` makes solution scalable

- Be default elements in `TreeSet` are sorted alphabetically.Order can be changed
- To test
  uniqueness use method `tSet.contains()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the answer I was looking for. 


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        String user_name[] = new String[3];
        String user_number[] = {"one","two","three"};
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Program title and info
        System.out.println("Welcome to Price Name Sorter.");
        System.out.println("All names must be unique.");

        //Prompt user for input and get input
        System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
        user_name[0] = s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Second Name: ");
        user_name[1] = s.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Third Name: ");
        user_name[2] = s.nextLine();

        //checks if there are any equal names
        for(int i = 0; i < (user_name.length-1); i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < user_name.length; j++)
            {
                if(user_name[i].equals(user_name[j]))
                {
                    System.out.println("\nNames " + user_number[i] + " " + user_number[j] + " are equal.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        //sort names
        Arrays.sort(user_name);

        System.out.println("Here are the sorted names");
        for(int i = 0; i < user_name.length; i++)
            System.out.println(user_name[i]);
    }

}
```